# Discord.py - Custom emojis randomly not showing in embed

Tags: python, async-await, discord, discord.py

I have written a discord bot using discord.py to randomly select 3 lords from a list. Since embeds can only display one image, I've decided to use custom emojis instead. It works, but the problem is that the sometimes emoji is not added.

Correct output:

[image]

Incorrect output:

[image]

I am pretty sure it is connected to problems with the async nature of the discord.py library and my code, but I don't exactly know how to fix it.

How do I make sure that the emotes are added before I try to fetch them and add them to the embed?

Also, any suggestions for a solution that wouldn't use custom emotes and would achieve something similar to the correct output, are welcome.

Here's the relevant part of the code and what it does:

1. Pick random lords from a list
2. For each lord:

   - create emote (add_emote method)
   - get respective custom emote
   - add custom emote to an embed as a field
3. Send the embed to the channel
4. Delete all custom emotes

```
@bot.command()
async def draft(ctx, counter):

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title='Lords'
    )

    if int(counter) > 3 or int(counter) < 1:

        rand_lords = random.sample(lords, counter)

        for rand_lord in rand_lords:
            await add_emote(ctx, rand_lord)
            emoji = get(ctx.message.guild.emojis, name=rand_lord['asset'])
            embed.add_field(name=rand_lord["lord"], value=emoji, inline=False)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    
    await remove_emote(ctx)
```

add_emote method:

```
async def add_emote(ctx, lord):
    with open('assets/' + lord['asset'] + '.webp', 'rb') as fd:
        await ctx.guild.create_custom_emoji(name=lord['asset'], image=fd.read())
```

lords.json:

```
[  
  {
    "race": "Bretonnia",
    "faction": "Couronne",
    "lord": "Louen Leoncoeur",
    "asset": "louen_leoncoeur"
  },
  {
    "race": "Bretonnia",
    "faction": "Bordeleaux Errant",
    "lord": "Alberic de Bordeleaux",
    "asset": "alberic_de_bordeleaux"
  },
  {
    "race": "Bretonnia",
    "faction": "Carcassonne",
    "lord": "The Fay Enchantress",
    "asset": "the_fay_enchantress"
  }
]
```

Comment: `create_custom_emoji` returns the created emoji, so why not make that the return value of `add_emote` and then you don't even need to do get.

Comment: @DenverCoder1 Thanks - that seems to have fixed the issue. Tested it a bit and the issue seems to be gone. I'll add the solution as a comment to this post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DenverCoder1 from the comments section, I was able to fix it:

Removed get() in the problematic loop:

```
        for rand_lord in rand_lords:
            emoji = await add_emote(ctx, rand_lord)
            embed.add_field(name=rand_lord["lord"], value=emoji, inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```